# Using constructors from abstract classes in other classes

Tags: c++

I am new to cpp and so far I have the following:

Shape hpp:

```
    class Shape
{
public:
    Shape(int x, int y);
    ~Shape();
    virtual void area();
    bool positive(int x, y);
private: 
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

Shape cpp:

```
Shape::Shape(int x, int y)
{
    x = x;
    y = y;
}

bool Shape::positive(int x, int y)
{
    return true;
}
```

Square hpp:

```
class Square : public Shape
{
private:
    virtual void area();
};
```

And Square cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Shape::area() 
{
  cout << "Temp" << endl;
}
```

I am trying to call the code from Main like so:

```
 Square sq;
 sq.area();
```

This is not working and I know I am missing something to do with the constructor of the Square class however I am not sure how the inheritance works in cpp and am struggling to understand it.

A explanation through corrections to the example would be very useful or link to a good tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `Shape::area` instead of `Square::area` in Shape.cpp. Replace: `void Shape::area()` with `void Square::area()`.

Also, you are trying to instantiate a `Square` object with default constructor even if it has none. Use:

```
Square sq(a, b);
```

instead, or define one.

Try to avoid `using namespace std` and get used to the `std::` prefix. It will be useful in the future.

And finally, I don't see any definition for `virtual void Shape::area()`. You probably meant to declare it *pure virtual*:

```
virtual void area() = 0;
```

On this note, the destructor of `Shape` should be declared virtual:

```
virtual ~Shape();
```

if you intend the class to be used polymorphically.

You also haven't defined a constructor for `Square`, which is needed, since the default constructor is not viable anymore (because none is available in `Shape`). Just define one like this:

```
class Square {
public:
    Square(int x, int y) : Shape(x, y) {}
    // ...
};
```

The above constructor will delegate the construction of the subobject `Shape` to the proper constructor.

Not to mention that in:

```
Shape::Shape(int x, int y)
{
    x = x;
    y = y;
}
```

you are *shadowing* the member objects `x` and `y`. What you probably meant is:

```
Shape::Shape(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those errors, I have changed them but now I am getting `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Square' ` talking about `Square sq = Square(2,3)`

Comment: @user3223763 You haven't defined any constructor for `Square`.

Comment: @Jefffrey I have editted the code and this is what error I am getting   http://fixee.org/paste/qe4ybjc/ also I don't see why the square constructor is necessary as there is one in `shape` `shape(int x, int y);` which is then implemented in `shape.cpp`

Comment: @user3223763, because that's how C++ works. Let me rewrite your code entirely. Just wait 3 minutes.

Comment: @user3223763, [**here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9b196ffee0b26b3)'s the working code. Study this.

Answer (score 2):

All your code is full of errors.
For example you forgot to specify a type specifier for the second parameter in this function

```
bool positive(int x, y);
```

Instead should be

```
bool positive(int x, int y);
```

This constructor

```
Shape::Shape(int x, int y)
{
    x = x;
    y = y;
}
```

does not initialize data members x and y. Instead it simply reassigns parameters x and y. The constructor should be written either as

```
Shape::Shape(int x, int y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

or as

```
Shape::Shape(int x, int y) : x( x ), y( y ) {}
```

Class Square should have a constructor with two parameters that it can delegeate these parameters to its base class constructor. For example

```
Square( int x, int y ) : Shape( x, y ) {}
```

Also take into account that you have no an abstract class. Abstract class is a class that has a pure virtual function. Your class Shape could be an abstract class if you for example declare virtual function square as

```
virtual void area() = 0;
```

I advice you to read some book on C++ for beginners.